# Parse number string digits

Tags: go, strconv

I am trying to calculate the multiplication result of a few digits which are part of a long digits string. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    inputNum := "73167176531330624919225119"
    mult := getMult(3, inputNum)

    fmt.Printf("Mult = %d", mult)

}

func getMult(startIndex int, inputNum string) int {
    mult := 0
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {

        digit, err := strconv.Atoi(string(inputNum[startIndex+i]))

        if err != nil {
            mult *= int(digit)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting %s to int  : %s\n", string(inputNum[startIndex+i]), err.Error())
        }

    }
    return mult
}
```

The result I want to get is 6*7*1*7*6*5*3*1*3*3 = 238140

But I an getting a runtime error:

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x20 pc=0x40130e]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.getMult(0x3, 0x534d40, 0x1a, 0x4d2701)
    test.go:25 +0x17e
main.main()
    test.go:10 +0x55
exit status 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code will work with fixing these two typos:
change `mult := 0` to `mult := 1`
and change `err != nil` to `err == nil` like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    inputNum := "73167176531330624919225119"
    mult := getMult(3, inputNum)
    fmt.Printf("Mult = %d", mult)
}

func getMult(startIndex int, inputNum string) int {
    mult := 1
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        digit, err := strconv.Atoi(string(inputNum[startIndex+i]))
        if err == nil {
            mult *= int(digit)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting %s to int  : %s\n", string(inputNum[startIndex+i]), err.Error())
        }
    }
    return mult
}
```

also you may use `inputNum[3:13]` to get new string from index 3 with length 10,
and you may use `int(v - '0')` to convert one character to integer number,
then use `for` `range` like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    inputNum := "73167176531330624919225119"
    mult := getMult(inputNum[3:13])
    fmt.Printf("Mult = %d \n", mult) // Mult = 238140
}

func getMult(str string) int {
    m := 1
    for _, v := range str {
        if v >= '0' && v <= '9' {
            m *= int(v - '0')
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting %q to int\n", v)
            break
        }
    }
    return m
}
```

output:

```
Mult = 238140
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems...

First, you need to start mult at 1, otherwise you will just continually multiply by 0 and always get 0.

Secondly you have the logic for your err check flipped.  It should be `if err == nil`

This seems to do what you want:

```
func getMult(startIndex int, inputNum string) int {
    mult := 1
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        digit, err := strconv.Atoi(string(inputNum[startIndex+i]))
        if err == nil {
            mult *= int(digit)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

    }
    return mult
}
```

The error you were getting was because you were trying to print `err.Error()` when `err` itself was nil (due to the logical flip of != and ==)